# Adding custom overlay data to Google street view

Tags: google-street-view

[This link](https://embed.tourdash.com/embed/b3e0dd4eaabf4b4f9d89f4437767f467?style=medium) uses an indoor version of google street view.

If you move around, it displays information on various plants.
Has anyone had any experience in doing this? If you how is it done? I've been asked to do the same kind of thing.

Answer (score -1):

i have done similar project. i may able to help you with your project, its kind of complicated, so i will just show a a demo

http://statefishandgame.com/v6209/

user name: audel6209
pass: audel6209

then click on "view all virtual tours" . then click 'edit' on one of the virtual tours.